# jQuery on() doesn't work when switching classes

Tags: jquery

[edit]
**THIS CODE DOES WORK**

Found out had multiple on() handlers on the same event/class.
[/edit]

I'm using the following code:

```
$selector.on('click', '.heya', function($e){
     alert('heya');
     jQuery(this).attr('class', 'byebye');
});


$selector.on('click', '.byebye', function($e){
     alert('byebye');
     jQuery(this).attr('class', 'heya');
});
```

Now clicking one of the elements once works correctly, but when clicking it again both callbacks are called. Somehow the previous "on()" trigger did not get removed. Anyone knows why?
I know I can solve this issue differently, but this would be the cleanest solution...

Comment: Your code works fine here; only the correct click event handler is executed based on the current class of the element: http://jsfiddle.net/ex63qqu8/

Comment: Can you post your html might be an issue there?

Comment: The problem is probably with `$selector`.

Comment: mm so far for simplifying my code ;( tnx.. I'll have another look of what's going on..

Answer (score 2):

Use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) methods instead.

```
$selector.on('click', '.heya', function($e){
     alert('heya');
     $(this).removeClass("heya").addClass("byebye");
});

$selector.on('click', '.byebye', function($e){
     alert('byebye');
     $(this).removeClass("byebye").addClass("heya");
});
```

Comment: While this is a good idea, I don't see how it will solve the problem.

Comment: Been there, done that.. does not work.
By that, while in some instances it might be preferred to do so.. sometimes calling just one method instead of 2 is better (as in less is more)

Comment: Ok, using your approach can break the styling if one day you add more classes in the markup. Could that be fixed by adding a return statement? Not able to test now..

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will help you to solve your problem.

```
$(".heya").on('click', function($e){
     alert('heya');
     $(this).attr('class', 'byebye');
});


$(".byebye").on('click', function($e){
     alert('byebye');
     $(this).attr('class', 'heya');
});
```

Comment: No way. This binds them based on their class when the page is loaded. You have to use delegation if classes change dynamically.

Comment: The hole thing about using on() is that you are not actualy binding an event to every element, but just one event to the parent element. This makes it much nicer when you are trying to bind a click to a 1000 elements. Your method will probably work but is nothing better that using jQuery('.heya').click() and will create a 1000 event handlers instead of just 1.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$(".heya,.byebye").on('click', function($e){

     $(this).toggleClass('byebye heya');

});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ex63qqu8/1/)**